# Observable vs Promise, how to wait for all observables to complete?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, observable

In Node.js I need to wait for several `Observable`s to finish. I also need to subscribe to each observable.

I'd use `Promise.all()` but those are `Observable`s not `Promise`.

Is the following code correct?

```js
let promise1 = observable1.toPromise()
observable1.subscribe(...)
let promise2 = observable2.toPromise()
observable2.subscribe(...)
Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(...)
```

If it is not correct, how to change it?

I tried this code:

```js
      let courtsPromise =
        this.ownedContractHandle.pastEvents({fromBlock: 0, filter: {courtId: this.courtIDs}})
          .subscribe(events => this.processCourtEvents(events))
      let namesPromise =
        this.courtNamesContractHandle.pastEvents({fromBlock: 0, filter: {ourCourtId: this.props.courtId}})
          .subscribe(events => this.processNameEvents(events))
      let trustedCourtsPromise =
        this.ownedContractHandle.getTrustedCourtsList(this.props.courtId)
      console.log('before zip')
      zip([courtsPromise, namesPromise]).subscribe(function(values) {
        console.log('values', values)
        this.updateCourtItems()
        this.updateTokenNames()
        this.updateTrustedCourts(values[2])
      })
```

It prints `'before zip'` but not `'values'`. Why does it not work?

Also you see, among two observables I have also a promise. How to wait for it, too (when both two observables and one promise complete)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think forkJoin is the operator you are looking for. It is the operator that will behave the closest to Promise.all(). It waits for all the observables to finish, then gives you all the values once. Use it like:

`forkJoin(observable1, observable2, observable3)
  .subscribe(([value1, value2, value3]) => {
    // Do what you want with the values
  })`

Be aware though that forkJoin will not emit anything before all the observables has finished. If you want to get all the values that is emitted by the the observables, not just the last one, you can use the sibling of forkJoin called combineLatest, like:

`combineLatest(observable1, observable2, observable3)`

To answer your side question about adding a promise into the stream, you can do that by using the from operator, like this:

`forkJoin(observable1, observable, from(myPromise) )`

Answer (score 5):

you mean something like zip?

Reference: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip

Copied an example from the above link to a stackblitz. Hope it will help

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-cb55fc?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: You are using subscribe. Don't use it on single observables. Use pipe so that they can return values.

Comment: Give a code example: I do not understand how to use pipe().

Comment: "Pipe is used to combine functional operators into a chain." But how to inspect individual events? I need to inspect events, not to pipe. And why not to use subscribe? Please, give a code sample.

Comment: I'll take an hour to get to my laptop. Will send an example then

Answer (score 1):

This should really be a comment not an answer (and being a month late, really addressed to other readers),  but when confronted with this question the problem may not actually be that you need to wait for all observable to complete, but that your observables should actually be promises.

As per https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable  Observables and Promises are for two different use cases.  If you're saying "I know how to do this with promises" then the answer is, probably, promises are the right solution.

I can't say for sure, but based on the names (pastEvents, and getTrustedCourtList, sound an awful lot like basic "getter" type functionality) of your functions and the way you are using them it looks a lot you're using Observables to co-ordinate async work.  That's what promises are for.

If you just need to do Step A, B & C, and when they complete, use the results for Step D,  that's promises not Observables.

If you only care about what happens at completion, chances are you really just want a promise.

That said, my opinion is that Observables are "infectious", i.e., once you've got it, you got to keep using them.  Using "toPromise" is always a bit risky since it makes assumptions about how the observable will be have, that aren't necessarily valid, so if you can't change any if the underlying objects to promises, you probably should stick with observables.